# Parsing html numbers like "&#189" in dom parser - android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, special-characters

I am developing an android project. I am using dom parser to parse the xml file. Issue is my xml file contains html numbers like &#189 (semicolon will come in the end of every char code)

for example

```
<quote>We &#8220;love&#8221; our nation</quote>
```

which is nothing but

```
<quot>We "love" our nation</quote>
```

I am not able to parse this html number in dom parse, when I try to get the node value, I am getting null.

Can anyone tel me how to parse this html character codes?

or

How to convert this html char code as either text char code or unicode char set in my xml feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used xmlpullparser. Its working fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar question here: [Android decoding html in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131906/android-decoding-html-in-xml-file)

It seems the html characters break the DOM parser, so it is unable to get the string from the xml entity.

There is a HTML function to parse HTML in a string:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
String s = <quote>We &#8220;love&#8221; our nation</quote>";
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Outputs:

> We "love" our nation

However it seems the DOM isn't getting the string to convert, so the following article maybe useful: [Using XPATH and HTML Cleaner to parse HTML / XML](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur reply. link u have given was useful.