# Error paring XML with apostrophy as &#039;

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xml

I'm trying to parse an XML feed using DOM. When a node looks like this:

```
<title>&#039;Star Wars&#039; May the force live</title>
```

the returned XML is only ' and then the parser continues on to the next node.

Here's how I'm parsing it:

```
NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int j=0; j<list.getLength(); j++) {
        Node innerItem = list.item(j);
        String name = innerItem.getNodeName();

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            vo.setTitle(innerItem.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this? The code parses fine in Android 4, but fails in Android 2.3.3

Comment: This seems to help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182536/748317

Comment: You may also try and use an XmlPullParser which is a standard way of processing XML in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your question is very much similar to this one: [android decoding html in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131906/android-decoding-html-in-xml-file)

It seems HTML characters break the DOM parser, so it is unable to get the string from the xml entity. There is a HTML function to parse HTML in a string.

```
TextView tv;
String s = "<quote>&#039;Star Wars&#039; May the force live</quote>";
tv.setText(HTML.fromHtml(s));
```

Outputs:

```
"Star Wars" May the force live
```

However it seems the DOM isn't getting the string to convert, so the following article maybe useful: [Using XPATH and HTML Cleaner to parse HTML/XML](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)